# On the usage of “turn” in spy stories

Tags: word-usage, etymology, american-english, british-english

The following meaning of turn appears to be common mainly in spy stories and, apparently, is present only in very few dictionaries.

From the OED:

> (29. c.) definition of the verb turn (transitive): "To induce or persuade (a person) to act against his country, former associates, etc., esp. as a spy”

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn):

> (27 - transitive)
>   to cause (an enemy agent) to become a double agent working for one's own side. - 
>   “*the bureau turned some of the spies it had caught*”

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/turn) has nothing on the above  usage so I’d like to ask:

- Was the above connotation of turn coined by spy story writers, or was it first used by journalists in real espionage stories.
- When does this  usage date back to? Was it AmE or BrE originally?
- Is [corrupt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/corrupt#dataset-cacd) a synonym of turn here,  or do they convey different  connotations? For instance, using Collins’ example, “*the bureau turned some of the spies it had caught*”, if I used “corrupted” in place  of “turned”, would the meaning change?

Comment: What was the date of the first quote for the OED entry 29c? I would think that would answer your first two questions. 'corrupt', though it fits for the same situation, means and insinuates very different things. 'corrupt' is from the point of view of where it was turned _from_, the idea of a traitor to the first cause.

Comment: @Mitch - well,  in a number of cases users on ELU have found earlier instances than those suggested by the OED, and also the original sources may be different. On the difference with corrupt, you might elaborate a more detailed post if you care.

Comment: The OED subdefinition 29c that you cite follows (and is supplemental to) their main definition 29: *trans. To induce or **persuade to adopt a (different) religious faith** (usually with implication of its truth or excellence), or a religious or godly (instead of an irreligious or ungodly) life; to convert; less commonly in bad sense, to pervert (cf. 14). Obs. or merged in other senses, except as in 1c.* Where definition 1c is *to perform by revolving, as a somersault*. Which to me means the spy defection / conversion usage is a trivial metaphoric resurrection of a usage dating back to C13.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don’t have access to the OED and the definition was taken from a different source which cited the OED. Interestly it appears that turn was taken from a religious usage in that respect.

Comment: The full OED's entry for ***turn*** is nearly as long as the one for ***set*** (stereotypically, the word with the longest definition in English dictionaries). But to be honest I think the distinction between switching allegiance to a particular religious faith or to a particular country's security services is so trivial it's barely worth explicitly providing a separate (sub-)definition. I'd say it might well have been used in the "spy" sense way back in Shakespeare's time - the fact that we don't have unambiguous written evidence of that *(**yet**?!)*  may be just an accident of history.

Comment: 'turning' spy has to be as old as humanity, and in AmE as old as the language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don’t think there  is anything trivial the way words evolve and change or add new connotations. The religious aspect appears to be less common nowadays, and if you know where Shakespeare used turn referring to spies, please let us know.

Comment: @lbf - really? so why do most dictionaries fail to mention this ever-existing term?

Comment: I think you're making *far* too much of what's barely even an "extension" of meaning. For at least 800 years it's been possible to "turn" someone, in the sense of persuading or forcing them to change allegiance, adopt a different lifestyle, etc. Do we really expect a new dictionary entry every time a general-purpose usage like that happens to be applied to a different *subject* with inconstant loyalty? When exactly did ***the worm turn**?*

Comment: "present in only very few dictionaries"? Really? You have it in Collins and OED, and [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/turn?s=t) (which appears to use Random House Unabridged Dictionary) has it as meaning 57. Personally I'd have guessed the usage had its roots in the word "turncoat".

Comment: @lbf: ***Poachers have been turning gamekeepers*** for a long time too! But whereas that way round we assume those poachers *made their own decision* to "switch sides", it's at least theoretically possible to say ***Gamekeepers have been turning poachers*** with the intended meaning *Gamekeepers have been persuading people to stop poaching [and become gamekeepers instead]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, was *see* a typo for *set* (the longest entry in the 2nd ed. of the OED)?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Actually, it was my brain fart. I did actually "know" ***see*** was the biggie, but wasn't thinking straight at the time.

Answer (score 7):

One dictionary that has this definition is the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED47404/track?counter=8&search_id=27626), so I think it's safe to say it's a little older then the OED says:

> 18. (a) To shift allegiance (to or against sb., someone's side, etc.);—also refl.; also, cause (sb.) to shift loyalties; transfer (one's loyalty to sb.); (b) to change spiritual allegiance, undergo a spiritual conversion; convert (to Christ, a faith, etc.);—also refl.; also, cause (sb., a group, etc.) to undergo a spiritual conversion; change the spiritual nature of (a temple); (c) to apostatize; cause (sb.) to apostatize; pervert (a mind, heart, etc.), corrupt; **turnen to baddenesse**; **turnen oute**.

The (b) sense dates back to c1175, so it probably lead to the (a) sense, which dates back to c1300.

In particular, the following quote seems to have a similar structure ("turned him"):

> Wiþ Fortiger be þai nold
>   & turned hem al bi on acord
>   To Vter Pendragoun her lord;
>   <sub>[Of Arthour & of Merlin](http://archive.li/0PVhA#selection-9651.0-9659.28), c1330(?a1300)</sub>

---

As for whether it is synonymous with "corrupt", that probably depends on which side the person is switching to. If they're switching to the enemy, then you could say it's corruption. However, if they're switching to *our* side, then you might say they finally see the light ;)

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t think it was such an ancient usage. And I see that the b) definition cites also corrupt as a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

It comes as a very early verbing of a noun, in this case, the word 'turncoat'. Turncoat, in turn, came from the 1100's, in the [Rotuli Chartarum](https://books.google.com/books?id=KENNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP6#v=onepage&q&f=false) where two barons changed fealty from William Marshal, 1st Earl of Pembroke to King John. Thus they quite literally changed their coats of arms to something else. Turned the coat.

Comment: Can you link to the specific page where "turncoat" appears? According to the OED, "turncoat" only appeared in English in 1570, so I'm not sure this makes sense. I think the *Rotuli Chartarum* is in Latin.

Comment: Yes, plus turncoat meaning “change principles or party" suggests more a voluntary action made for personal reasons, rather than something that was the result of being “persuaded” by a third party.